# Bootstrap modal doesnt work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Addressbook</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
          <div id="myModal"  role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog" >
                 <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Contact</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                          <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="firstname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Firstname</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter Firstname">
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="middlename"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Middlename</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="middlename" placeholder="Enter Middlename">
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="lastname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Lastname</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="middlename" placeholder="Enter Lastname">
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="phone_number"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> Phone Number</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_number" placeholder="Enter number">
                    </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="address"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Addres</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Enter Addres">
                  </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"</script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"</script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

button Add new contact

```
<div class="panel-body">
      <div class="pull" ><a href="contacts.php">
       button class="btn btn-successdatatoggle="modal"datatarget="#myModal">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Add New Contact</button></a>   </div>
</div>
```

it is bootstrap modal structure,does not work any button,i can't understand why(
I have button Add new contacts,after clicking on button,i need to create modal.But after clicking nothing happens.Button in another page,modal on this page.i need this modal on another page,but i dont understand how.

Comment: not able to understand what problem your facing ..

Comment: Remove the 3 javascript lines where you including the files, one file (CDN) is enough to load the bootstrap library.

Comment: Start by using https://validator.w3.org/nu/ which will pick up a few obvious errors. Then look at the Network tab in your browser's developer tools and make sure that all your JS URLs are actually giving you JS back.

Comment: if copy the code ,you will see that ane button on this page doesnt work

Comment: Please create a repro on https://jsfiddle.net/ so we know the html is valid and can actually help instead of guessing.

Answer (score 0):

There is missing button tag in your code.Your button should like this;

```
<div class="panel-body">
      <div class="pull" >
            <a href="contacts.php">
                    <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Add New Contact</button>
            </a>   
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A button element isn't allowed where they are trying to put it.